# Custom screen resolution for a VirtualBox Mac guest?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, virtualization, resolution, virtualbox

**TL;DR** - *How do I set a custom screen resolution for a VirtualBox Mac guest?*

I'm in a situation where I need to keep Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6.8) alive in a VirtualBox setup to run some legacy software. The host machine is a 2013 MacBook Retina 13" running El Capitan (Mac OS X 10.11) Honestly, things are running pretty well... better than expected! The one irritation is that I can't set the resolution to something reasonable.

I've scoured the internet and followed lots of tutorials. The only thing that has been effective, has been [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=54030#p248180):

> To control GOP, use the following VBoxManage command:
>
> VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode N
>
> Where N can be one of 0,1,2,3,4 referring to the 640x480, 800x600,
>   1024x768, 1280x1024, 1440x900 screen resolution respectively.

While this is useful, I need a custom resolution of 1440x856... which will allow me to put the VM on a 1440x900 display with VirtualBox's top and bottom utility bars exposed without having to scroll the window around.

Is there a way to set a custom screen resolution for a Mac host and guest in VirtualBox?

Comment: You can try something like: `VBoxManage setextradata "VM Name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1920x1080`